# how to resolve import error with flask_mysqldb?

Tags: python, flask

I am having an import error with flask_mysqldb. I am receiving the following error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

[this is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAz0O.png)

It happens when I run this command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.d`

after which I get this response `"ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.d: File exists"`

I dont actually understand where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Give a bit more context, what OS? Installation Method?